# Python: Getting a list of values associated with a single key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

The task is to take all the movies associated with a dictionary of actors.

```
actor_dict = {'actor_A': [m1, m2, m3, m4], 'actor_B': [m5,m6,m7,m8]}
```

How can I single out the list of values from the entire dictionary?

Answer (score 4):

One possibility would be:

```
movies_list = []
for v in actor_dict.itervalues():
    movies_list.extend(v)
```

If you want unique movies (if one movie appears in more actors' lists):

```
movies_set = []
for v in actor_dict.itervalues():
    movies_set.update(v)
movies_list = list(movies_set)
```

or:

```
movies_list = list(reduce(set.union, map(set, d.itervalues())))
```

or (thanks to @DrTyrsa):

```
movies_list = list(set.union(*map(set, d.itervalues())))
```